# fatal error: 'apr.h' file not found when installing x-sendfile mac os x mountain lion server

Tags: apache, fatal-error, osx-mountain-lion, apr, x-sendfile

When I upgraded my Lion Server to Mountain Lion, it seems that it removed my mod_xsendfile from apache.

I followed the instructions from [this](http://elivz.com/blog/single/mod_xsendfile/) web site, but got stuck with a "No such file or directory" error.
With some help from google i found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/how-to-compile-mod-wsgi-on-mountain-lion-by-fixing-apxserror-command-failed-w) page that gave me the solution to this:
"sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain"

Looked good, but when I try to run "sudo apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c" I get a "fatal error: 'apr.h' file not found" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, still nothing new here. I even took the time to format and reinstall mac os x, but it didn't help.

Comment: When I tried to download and install the Xcode Command Line Tools from the Preferences pane. And after that created the symlink ("sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain"), it would install again.

But now I have the problem that x-sendfile doesn't seem to be loaded after a restart. No error, nothing. But "LoadModule xsendfile_module   libexec/apache2/mod_xsendfile.so" has been added to the httpd.conf.
Hmm... wierd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to re-install the Xcode command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

You'll then likely need to accept the Xcode license agreement again:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Once you've done that (as well as your symlink for the toolchain) you should be good to go.

Comment: Sir, you just saved me hours of headache. Here is my +1. Please take it :)

Comment: This is also still relevant for High Sierra.